# Flickery mouseover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

A While back i started a project which involved a page spliced in half, a link on either side, which when rolled over expanded the respective side.

here's that example;
http://camoconnell.com/ddu/

what i've discovered since 1st building this is the hover state and .stop() function, however i've tried these, and it didnt resolve the problems with the flickering on the righthand side.

any recommendations welcome,

thanks in advance

**edit**

Tried this with no result, updated the example link above accordingly

```
  $('.change').stop(true,true).hover(

    function() {
            // do something

    },function() {
            // do something

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )    
clearQueueA Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well.
Defaults to false.

jumpToEndA Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.
```

try using with true as both args

```
.stop(true,true)
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Edit you are trying it wrong

```
$('.change').hover(

    function() {
            $(this).stop(true,true);
            //now do something

    },function() {
            // do something

    }
);
```

Comment: well, its function ok on chrome, but behaves erratically on FF